# Returning __unsafe_unretained pointer to released object in Objective C causes a crash

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, unsafe-unretained

**Problem**:

I have an `__unsafe_unretained id` pointer that points to an already released object. So far so good, as long as I do not "use" the pointer at all (in particular, I do not call any method through the pointer). However, when I try to return its value from a method, it **crashes**, even if I have explicitly specified that the return value has the type `__unsafe_unretained id`. Why is that? I thought if I use `__unsafe_unretained`, it would not call methods like `retain` / `release` / `autorelease` at all? I thought I can use `__unsafe_unretained id` pretty much as if it is a `void*` (meaning that it only does simple, native assignments)?

**Environment**:

- Developing on `Xcode 4.4.1`
- Using `iOS SDK 5.1`
- `ARC` is `enabled`
- Running on `iPhone 4.3 / 5.0 / 5.1 Simulator` or `iPhone 4.3 Device`
- Crashes on both `Debug` and `Release` builds

**Source Code**:

```
// Declare my class with 1 member.
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    __unsafe_unretained id      m_MyMember;
}
@end

// **************************************************************************************************** //

// Implement my class.
@implementation MyClass

// Setter
-(void)SetMember:(__unsafe_unretained id)member
{
    m_MyMember = member;
}

// Getter: by passing parameter by reference
-(void)GetMember1:(__unsafe_unretained id*)member
{
    *member = m_MyMember;   // No problem.
}

// Getter: by return value
-(__unsafe_unretained id)GetMember2
{
    return m_MyMember;  // Crashed in here!
}

@end

// **************************************************************************************************** //

//! Application entry point.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {       
        {
            // Create an object that dies immediately. deadObj is a dangling pointer.
            __unsafe_unretained id deadObj = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 12];

            // Create my object.
            MyClass* myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];

            // Assign my member.
            [myObject SetMember:deadObj];

            // Get back my member: by passing parameter by reference
            __unsafe_unretained id unsafePointer1;
            [myObject GetMember1:&unsafePointer1];  // No problem.

            // Get back my member: by return value
            __unsafe_unretained id unsafePointer2;
            unsafePointer2 = [myObject GetMember2]; // Crashed in here!

            int BreakpointHere = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Call Stack** (iPhone 4.3 Simulator/iOS 4.3 Device):

```
#0  0x011db09b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00106712 in __arclite_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue at /SourceCache/arclite_host/arclite-29.1/source/arclite.m:259
#2  0x00001fec in -[MyClass GetMember2] at /Users/user/SourceCode/main.m:28
#3  0x00002147 in main at /Users/user/SourceCode/main.m:56
```

**Call Stack** (iPhone 5.0/5.1 Simulator):

```
#0  0x014f6d25 in objc_retain ()
#1  0x014f7fe3 in objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue ()
#2  0x00001fec in -[MyClass GetMember2] at /Users/user/SourceCode/main.m:28
#3  0x00002147 in main at /Users/user/SourceCode/main.m:56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior can be explained with the following information [3.2.3. Unretained return values](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.other-returns) in the *Automatic Reference Counting* documentation:

> A method or function which returns a retainable object type but does
>   not return a retained value must ensure that the object is still valid
>   across the return boundary.
>
> When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value
>   at the point of evaluation of the return statement, then leaves all
>   local scopes, and then balances out the retain while ensuring that the
>   value lives across the call boundary. In the worst case, this may
>   involve an autorelease, but callers must not assume that the value is
>   actually in the autorelease pool.

Your function `GetMember2` returns an `id`, which is a retainable object type. Therefore the ARC compiler adds `retain`/`autorelease` calls to make sure that the returned object is still valid when the function returns. This crashes because `m_MyMember` does not point to a valid object.

Declaring the return type as `(__unsafe_unretained id)` does not change this behavior, in fact I assume that the `__unsafe_unretained` is ignored here.

Comment: Lesson learned:
1. Always __nil__ an `__unsafe_unretained` pointer before its pointee dies.
2. Use `__weak` instead (requires iOS 5 runtime).